# is there a safe way to compile an electron app (with out npm security problems)?

Tags: security, npm, electron

i recently built an electron app using node js , html ,css , js
and have been wanting to compile it ive npm installed all options ifound (packager,build,forge) but npm says all have security issues is there asecure way to compile? (compile for windows)

Answer (score 0):

most of the security vulnerabilities are mostly in "build" packages, things that are run during compile time only, and not when the electron/nodejs app is in use, only when it's built/minified/etc, but they are not included in the final product.

Then also are most of those security vulnerabilities usually highly hypothetical, with a high threshold of prerequisites for the weakness to occur.

If you wish to be certain, read the security risk descriptions, what is required, and evaluate if it applies to your system, if it's in a build time package, or a runtime package, and what kind of vulnerability it represents.

if there is a vulnerability in a package that gets included in the app, and it is one that you need to fix because it would pose a serious threat to your end users, check the repository for the package, to see if someone already submitted a pull request for a fix that hasn't made it to the main branch, and merge that into your version that you use.

Comment: thank you, which compiler is the best and also I know it’s a beginner question but I want to be sure if my app only runs locally on a safe computer without connecting to  the web its vulnerability's can't be exploited right?

Comment: Don't worry too much. Just read the security descriptions. When needed investigate the code, and the requirements and evaulate if that applies to your build process or runtime app. But in the "real" world such worries are usually not applicable to small beginner applications to worry about.  Just regularly update your app if security vulnerabilities are found within runtime libraries that have a minimal chance to be exploitable.

Comment: alot of thanks so to summarize electron-packager is pretty safe and its not much of asecurity issue and if its offine its not much of asecurity threat (im being carefull cause its for my dads office to manage databases so it does use data )